# Assigning optional to nil in array

Tags: arrays, swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to create a method that takes an array of CGPoint optionals, and assigns each of them to nil. I am getting an error "Cannot assign a value of type nil to a value of type CGPoint?". I am confused because I thought that optionals could either be nil or some type of specified object. Thanks for any help (:

```
func resetArray(arr: [CGPoint?])
{
        for index in 0...arr.count-1
        {
            arr[index] = nil
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a parameter is passed to a function, it is immutable, so you are not allowed to change it. For arrays, being value types, that means you cannot use any `mutating` method or otherwise perform any action that changes the value.

You can make the parameter writeable by prefixing it with the `inout` modifier:

```
func resetArray(inout arr: [CGPoint?])
                ^^^^^
```

Note that, when invoking the function, the parameter must be passed by prefixing it with the `&` ampersand character:

```
var array = [...]
resetArray(&array)
           ^
```

You can also make a parameter modifiable, but with the changes visible from within the function body only (which means changes occur on a copy of the original parameter passed to the function) - that can be done by using the `var` modifier:

```
func resetArray(var arr: [CGPoint?])
                ^^^
```

Comment: So using inout will modify the original array?